# Is there some way to quickly run a console logging JavaScript script in Code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am new to VSCode, I need a way to quickly test a JavaScript script that only console logs. Anyone (i mean, you all probably know) know how one can achieve this feat?

All the code does is repeat the word "butts" in the console infinitely.

```
function butts() {
    for (; ;);
    console.log("butts")
    butts();
}
```

I understand theirs probably a million things wrong with the above, but i would like to learn them myself please.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is asking. What is it you are trying to do?

Comment: You call butts() from inside the function. Call it from the outside.

Answer (score 1):

**What are you trying to do?**

`for (; ;);` This itself is an un-definite loop, similar to :

```
for(; ;)
{
 ;//do nothing
}
```

calling function inside same function, causing a recursion. If you understand well, a recursive function must have a base/closing condition to stop recursion at a level.

```
function butt()
{
butt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
window.setInterval(function(){console.log('butts')}, 1);
```

This will write `butts` to the console every millisecond.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/cjmwyvj7/